# JavaScript Functions - Why does this work?

Tags: javascript

I've been doing server-side coding for some years, namely in Python, shell, and more recently, Java.  Although I've done some client-side JavaScript, I've never dug too deeply.

Until I found node.js and the stacks surrounding it.  Now I'm entranced.  I'm trying desperately to understand asynchronous programming and callback functions.  I am making progress, but then I found something that threw me back into the land of utter confusion and despair.

```
var add = new Function('num1', 'num2', 'return num1 + num2');
console.log(add(1, 2));

Outputs: 3
```

Can anyone explain to me like I'm 5, why and how this works?  The way I see it is, a function called "add" takes three parameters.  I pass numbers to the first two, but the last parameter is actual code.  Yes, I sort of understand that JavaScript functions are actually objects that contain strings of code (that hurt my brain a lot).  However, what causes the third parameter to "trigger."  How does JS know to execute the third parameter as if it were a line in the function itself, not a parameter.

Argh... sorry for the dumb question.  No, this is not a homework assignment, I'm old.  It isn't even for a real work project, I just like digging into stuff like this and this one is causing virtual tears.

Thanks,
TR

Comment: You missed a parenthesis in console.log(add(1,2));

Comment: This is the function constructor that creates and returns new function. It's not the usual way of creating functions. You can image that internally it does something like `return eval('function(' + arguments[0] + ',' + arguments[1] + '){' + arguments[2] '}');`. It's equivalent of doing `var add = function(num1, num2) { return num1 + num2; };`. If you want to learn about functions, have a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions

Comment: JS functions can have dynamic number of arguments and you can detect the last argument that passed to a function.

Comment: You can find more information [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments) and [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function)

Comment: @FelixKling why doing it that way though?

Comment: @Typo: Well, sometimes you have to build functions dynamically. Think about something like jsFiddle: You get code from an input and you want to wrap that into a function. Then you can do something like `(new Function('console, 'module', 'exports', someCode))(consoleImplementation, module, module.exports)`.

Comment: its a bit of an unrelated comment but the callbacks are the worst part of async programming in Javascript. Some other languages let you avoid the callback hell using coroutines / generators / async keyword / etc.

Comment: @hugomg: FWIW, ES6 introduces promises and generator. async and await keywords are planned for ES7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Function" is a constructor in Javascript.  This means that when you use the "new" keyword, you are  passing three parameters to the "Function" constructor.  The "Function" constructor returns a function, but don't confuse the returned function with the Function() call you are using as a constructor.

The "Function" constructor accepts 1 or more arguments.  The last argument is the function body and the remaining arguments are the function arguments.  So - in effect - your code does something like:

```
var add = function(num1, num2) {return num1 + num2};
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

When you use the `Function` constructor, it runs the same part of the Javascript compiler/interpreter that is used when processing Javascript in an HTML or JS file. It reads the last argument and converts it into a function body, just like that Javascript compiler does when loading a file.

So it's running the same Javascript compiler code that would have run if you'd loaded a file that contained:

```
function (num1, num2) { 
    return num1 + num2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The usual way to define functions is with

```
function add(x, y){
    return x + y;
}
```

or

```
var add = function(x, y){
    return x + y;
}
```

The `new Function` thing is more akin to `eval`, except that it builds a function instead of immediately running the code. You probably shouldnt use it all that much. Not only does it bypass your linter and mess up the optimizer, but unlike regular function, it does not inherit variables from the outer scope.

```
//this should return 3
function foo(x){
    function bar(){ return x; }
    return bar();
}

// This bersion of bar is going to try to read a global variable x instead.
function foo(x){
    var bar = new Function("return x;");
    return bar();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 new Function('num1', 'num2', 'return num1 + num2');
```

the first `num1` defines arguments[0], the second `num2` defines arguments[1], then the function body is the third argument.

ALso note there is no special scope when creating a function with the Function constructor, they are created in the global scope [0]

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function

Comment: I didn't down-vote you, but perhaps the down-voter thinks you think position 3 is always the function body, when the positioning is actually variable?  I'm up-voting you because of the link that makes this very clear.